# what is the difference between jblade, qblade, and xflr5 softwares?

Tags: design, simulation, turbines, aircraft-design, airfoils

I am working on a propeller design, and I've came through Jblade which helped me in the airfoil design, yet as I can remember, xflr5 can also do this...
doing some internet search, i found that Jblade is based on qblade and xflr5/xfoil... so does this mean the jblade is more accurate? or everyone of these 3 softwares has a specific field of application?
thanks

Comment: You might get more responses on the aviation SE site.

Comment: Ok thanks, i thought it would be an engineering question , but yeah its more aviation specific